# Is there anyway to change the color of a shape between .to calls?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/mVVYPa?editors=001)

JS:

```
function init(){
        var stage   = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
        var circle  = new Array();
        var randomColor = ["#019875", "#26C281", "#2ABB9B", "#36D7B7", "#1BA39C"];

        for(var x = 0; x < 300; x++){
            circle[x] = new createjs.Shape();
            circle[x].graphics.beginFill( randomColor[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) ]).drawCircle( Math.floor(Math.random() * 800), 0, 10);
            stage.addChild(circle[x]);

            createjs.Tween.get(circle[x], {loop: true})
                .to({y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 400), x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) }, 4000, createjs.Ease.backIn)
        .to({y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 700), x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) }, 8000, createjs.Ease.backIn)
        }

        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
```

I am trying to change the color of the circles in the above codepen when the circles are on their second .to call. Is this possible? If not, what would be a workaround?

Comment: Are you looking to tween the color, or just change it?

Comment: Here is an example where the color is set after the first `to` method. It uses a `call`, which changes the style of a stored fill command. I added a red color which is eligible during that call to emphasize the difference. http://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/MKyyJb?editors=001

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for. I didn't know about calling a .call function.